# MAC OS Catalina cannot compile latex from Terminal

Tags: terminal-output

I upgraded to Catalina and now I am not able to compile latex files in Terminal, the compiler runs but the classes are not read, the path to the .cls files is in /etc/paths, when I copy the .cls file to the folder in which the compiled file is the program runs until it calls for another package. Also I am not able to compile using pdflatex --shell-escape neither using TexWorks nor Texshop. Other compilations using Texworks or Texshop are ok, surely a problem with paths that I am not able to find ?

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using? What does `which pdflatex` and `echo $PATH` return when run in Terminal?

Comment: I am using Mac TeX; The returns are /opt/local/bin/pdflatex and /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex:/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex:/opt/local/libexec/texlive

Comment: Well, it appears that you have another partial TeX Distribution in /opt/local/bin which is found before the one in Mac TeX which is in /Library/TeX/texbin. Is there something in your .profile or .bash_profile that is setting that PATH (assuming you are using bash rather than zsh)? Finally, how are you tyring to compile with --shell-escape in TeXShop; are you using an engine of your own since by default shell escape is turned off in TeXShop?

Comment: No, nothing in my .bash that may cause this, it may be there from a previous TeX distribution (?). I am using TexShop with the --shell-escape option included in the preferences and runs ok. Tried the same in TexWorks with $synctexoption --tex-option=--shell-escape $fullname b ut does not work

Comment: Well, something is giving you a crazy PATH variable. Unless you figure out what is causing that and fix it I would suggest adding the line `export PATH=/Library/TeX/texbin:${PATH}` with a return as the last line in your .profile and/or your .bash_profile. Also, the default shell under Catalina is `zsh` rather than bash. Are you sure you're still using bash or have .zprofile set to read your .profile at login?

Comment: My terminal is zsh since I migrated to Catalina but now I do not have nor .zprofile neither .bash (at least I do not see .bash)

Comment: Is there a `.zshenv` in your HOME folder? Note that you need to run `ls -a ~` in Terminal to see any files whose names start with a period.

Comment: No, I have not such file

Comment: WAIT... you said you edited /etc/paths? WHY?! What is now in that file?

Comment: These are the contents of the /etc/paths file: /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
/bin
/sbin
/Library/TeX/texbin
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex
/opt/local/libexec/texlive

Comment: That file should never have been touched! First, remove the two direct references to /usr/local/texlive/2019/... since that will change if/when you update to another year's TeX Live. Try to move the /Library/TeX/texbin to the top of the file. You seem to have other stuff prepended to the path so I don't know where those are coming from. If you edit /etc/paths (which you did) the OS no longer picks up the information in the files in /etc/paths.d. Sigh!

Comment: Also, did you change /etc/profile and/or /etc/zprofile?

Comment: No, I did not change any other file, I edited /etc/paths after googling for solutions. I made the changes you suggest but to no avail, I will check my backups to see what are the differences between the current /etc/paths and older versions